# Count lines in very large file where line size is fixed

Tags: python, file

I have a very large CSV file (6.2 GB). I want to calculate how many lines it has using python. What I currently have is the following:

```
import time

file_name = 'TickStory/EURUSD.csv'    
start = time.time()

with open(file_name) as f:
    line_count = sum(1 for line in f)

print(line_count)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Every column in the file has a fixed number of characters. The content of the file is as follows:

> ```
> Timestamp,Bid price
> 2012-01-01 22:00:36.416,1.29368
> 2012-01-01 22:00:40.548,1.29366
> 2012-01-01 22:01:48.884,1.29365
> 2012-01-01 22:01:53.775,1.29365
> 2012-01-01 22:01:54.594,1.29366
> 2012-01-01 22:01:55.390,1.29367
> 2012-01-01 22:02:40.765,1.29368
> 2012-01-01 22:02:41.027,1.29368
> ...
> ...
> ```

My current code takes around 49.99 seconds. Is there any way to make it faster?

Thanks in advance.

**N.B:** There are a lot of available solutions for finding line count cheaply using python. However, my situation is different than others because in my file all the lines have a fixed number of characters (except the header line). Is there any way to use that to my advantage?

Comment: Are you running on a unix like OS?

Comment: I use both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @BlackThunder my situation is different from the one you mentioned. I already clarified that all the lines in my CSV file have a fixed number of characters. I needed to find a way to use that property to my advantage.

Comment: Does all the lines have the same number?

Comment: @BlackThunder all the lines except the header line has the same number of characters. The values are different, but should it matter?

Comment: And does the header line occurs once only?

Comment: @BlackThunder Yes

Comment: @Tanmoy FYI I just edited the title to distinguish your question from others

Comment: how long does it take for readlines to run on the file?  if it is acceptable then use len(reader.readlines()))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each row has a fixed number of characters, just get the file's size in bytes with [`os.path.getsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize), subtract the length of the header, then divide by the length of each row. Something like this:

```
import os

file_name = 'TickStory/EURUSD.csv'

len_head = len('Timestamp,Bid price\n')
len_row = len('2012-01-01 22:00:36.416,1.29368\n')

size = os.path.getsize(file_name)

print((size - len_head) / len_row + 1)
```

This assumes all characters in the file are 1 byte.

Comment: @BlackThunder you probably have Windows line endings (\r\n) in that case.

Comment: @wjandrea Your solution works, but I have to adjust for '\r\n' in windows machine. Is there any way I can automatically manage when there is '\r\n' in the line and when there is only '\n'?

Comment: @Wodin I knew what was in my file. I edited the setup according to it. It missed 9 lines out of 90000000.

Comment: @Tanmoy Just to be clear, you're talking about different files with different line endings, right? Cause your question says you have only one file.

Comment: @BlackThunder Does each row in the file you tested have the same number of characters, like OP's? Is `os.path.getsize` correct?

Comment: @BlackThunder So I forgot to count the header line, but that's the only problem I can find so far. I confirmed it worked on the subset that OP provided. Try doing the math yourself and see if it works out: `size == row_length * number_of_lines + header_length`

Comment: @Tanmoy If you're only opening files with Windows line endings on Windows, and vice-versa for Unix, you could use `os.linesep`. Otherwise you could specify the line ending as an argument to the script.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I was talking about two different files on two different machines. The CSV file in my windows machine had \r\n as line ending and the CSV file on my Linux machine had \n line ending. This is what was causing the confusion. However, it's fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the time might not change much as you still have to load the whole file in memory. You can try this as you dont have to iterate through the file and python would do it for you:

```
import csv

with open('TickStory/EURUSD.csv',"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)
    print(row_count)
```

In such a case I would suggest to just maintain **an additional file containing metadata of this file with row_count and other details** and taking care to update the metadata when an update is made to the file.

Comment: `for line in f` doesn't load the whole file into memory, but your solution seems to...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Would this be in anyway faster?

Comment: I assume it would be significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) on your ubuntu machine

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['wc', '-l', filename], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: I just tested this on a random big file and got about the same speed as OP's code.